# Is there a way to check if an extension is enabled from within the extension?

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions

I have an extension which needs to be on for some sites and off for others, however it is creating a page on all the sites even when disabled.

Is there a way for an extension to check if it is enabled for output for a specific store id?

I'm using:

```
 $enabled =  Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Module_Name');
```

But this returns 1 if echoed out, as the module is enabled in general, therefore the hook is still making a page even if the output is disabled.

**Updated code based on answer** - but still rendering to the blank page:

```
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/module_name',$store_id) == 35)
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }else{
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function canShowTab()
{
    return Mage::helper('Core')->isModuleEnabled('Vendor_Module');
}
```

OR

```
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/module_name',$store_id) == 1)
{
    return false
}else{
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is showing enabled because the extension is enabled in general - I need this on a store level.

Comment: @Aravona, Check my updated answer

Comment: hi this does absolutely nothing and still causes the page to render blank.